# Error when trying to open stores in Outlook plugin

Tags: .net, plugins, outlook, vsto

Sometimes I have the following error when trying to open stores in a Outlook plugin I made:

```
Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Message: Impossible d'ouvrir la banque d'informations.
StackTrace:    à Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.StoresClass.get_Item(Object Index)
```

Which I guess in english would be:

```
Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Message: The information store cannot be opened.
StackTrace:    à Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.StoresClass.get_Item(Object Index)
```

The error **does not occur everytime** the plugins is launched. I have not idea why it cannot be open and wondered if someone got an idea.
Sometimes it will never open, so long as I do not reboot the computer for example.

Is it because it is used by another process or something like that?
Could not find another occurence of this error anywhere else.

Comment: So **is** the PST file opened in another process? Keep in mind that the PST provider can share PST files between different processes as long as they are running in the same security context.

Answer (score 1):

According to your descriptions, I assume you want to open stores in an Outlook plugin.

The error which you provided shows that you are using the wrong object model.

StoresClass Object model does not provide ability to get stored data.

The following code is the mail item I got by using the StoreClass object model.

```
 Outlook.Store store;
    NameSpace space;
    Stores stores;
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        space = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        store = space.DefaultStore;
        string str = store.DisplayName;
        MAPIFolder folder = store.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);  
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(str);
        Items items = folder.Items;
        MailItem item = items[1];
        item.Display();
    }
```

For more information, You can check the link below.

[StoreClass Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.storeclass?view=outlook-pia)